# Values FROM and TO

Tags: forms

I am really a person who can just code the logic and have very little creativity. What kind of form do advise me to use for this data:

> MAC Adress for all slots
>   from 00-21-5A-9C-D5-00
>   to 00-21-5A-9C-D5-FF

The 2 addresses will be text inputs.

I was thinking about using Material design and the output could look like this:

> MAC Adress for all slots
>   from __________________
>   to ___________________

OR

> MAC Adress
>
> From [ _________ ]                To [ _________ ]

Can you please advise me?

Comment: The values will be typed, right?

Comment: Yes, they will be typed, Alvaro.

Comment: "text inputs" sorry I misread. Your second option is more clear in my opinion. Label in one line (add "for all slots") and options in second line. Use a placeholder to indicate an example of what could be entered.

Comment: Thx for the opinion.

Comment: Mac addresses look quite complex, how will people know the from and to values?

Comment: It's a requirement of the group. They are networkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be more descriptive like:

```
Filter results -----------------------------------------------
| 
| Only show slots with MAC Address between [___________] and [___________]
| 
| Describe some other filter [_________]
|
+------------------------------------------------------
```

It REALLY depends on who you are designing it for:
* Someone who uses this every few days generally want quick terse forms - hide any help behind a (?) icon - they can click the first time to learn more.
* Someone who will only use this page at most once a month will prefer to be guided through the process with a more description form.

Likewise using technical words/abbreviations helps where everyone knows the terms used, but hinders where enough people don't know.

Eg in the library system I designed, the daily staff item check in / check out forms would be terse and quick to use. The stock take module was more descriptive because most libraries would only do it yearly and they would forget how to use the more advanced features. The age / education of the patrons for patron interface also impacted design (primary verses secondary versus tertiary schools)